# Recreate the Siri-like curley quotes in iOS

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont, siri

I'm not sure if they use an image or if it's some kind of text transformation, but how does apple achieve the curly quote style found in Siri responses? When I attempt to recreate it with regular quotes I get just that, regular quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they are using the UNICODE "Left Double Quotation" and "Right Double Quotation" marks -- code point U+201C (“) and U+201D (”).  You can embed them directly into your source (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Typing_quotation_marks_on_a_computer_keyboard) for how to type them).

```
bash$ cat foo.m
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int
main() {
    NSLog(@"“%@”\n", @"Hello");
    return 0;
}
bash$ gcc foo.m -framework Foundation
bash$ ./a.out
“Hello”
```

You can embed them as UTF-8 sequences using hex escapes as well:

```
    NSLog(@"\xE2\x80\x9C%@\xE2\x80\x9D\n", @"Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

They are called "smart quotes" or "book quotes", which is a different Unicode code point than regular quotes. The unicode code point for smart quotes are `U+201C` for the "Left double quotation mark" and `U+201D` for the "Right double quotation mark". Compare that to `U+0022` which is "Quotation mark".